# Angular/Laravel - getting 'No query results for model [App\Models\User]' error

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I'm working with Laravel and Angular. I want to display the authenticated user's data. I'm getting datas from Laravel with JSON and I'm using this code for the user datas.

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
});

this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user', {headers}).subscribe(
  result => (this.user = result, console.log(result))
);
```

It's working but after a certain time this code does not work and I'm getting the error in console.

> No query results for model [App\Models\User]
>
> 127.0.0.1:8000/api/user 404 (Not Found)

What am I missing?

##### `UserController`

```
public function user() {
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::id())->firstOrfail();

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

##### `api.php`

```
Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'user']);
```

Comment: If you are already logged in (passed all middlewares and auth checks) you can do 1 line of code: `return response()->json(Auth::user());`. You have `Auth::user()` it will return the logged in `user`, `Auth::id()` it will return the user's `id`. And whenever you do `where('id', $id)` and then `->first()` or `->firstOrFail()`, you can do `User::find($id);` and forget about `where` or if you use the `fail`, you can do `User::findOrFail($id);`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your session is ending and that's why Auth::id() returns empty and can't find your username

Comment: no I have authguard, If there was such a thing, it should redirect to the 'login' page.